# Выведите все числа от 0 до 100, содержащие цифру 2. Также выведите кол-во этих чисел. Python.Помогите решить!

Tags: python

Выведите все числа от 0 до 100, содержащие цифру 2. Также выведите кол-во этих чисел.
Помогите пожалуйста решить задание по python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу пожалуй достаточно тупое решение, но на промежутке от 0 до 100 работать будет с нормальной скоростью.

```
cnt = 0
for i in range(0, 101):
    if "2" in str(i):
        print(i)
        cnt += 1

 print("Count:", cnt)
```

Суть решение: мы просто перебираем все числа в заданном диапазоне, конвертируем их в строку и проверяем вхождение символа '2' в этой строке.